# Перемещение элементов одного массива в другой.

Tags: массивы, android, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой вот код:

```
String msb0 = doc.childNode(0).toString();
String[] msb = msb0.split("</td>");
for(int i = 36; i <= msb.length  - 1; i = i + 14) 
{
titleList.add(msb[i].toString());
}
```

В массиве выводятся куски хтмл-кода:

```
<td class="data">текст
```

Подскажите, как отобранные в цикле элементы массива msb засунуть в новый массив.
И как удалить кусок хтмл-кода, чтобы остался только текст?

Comment:     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(titleList);

Comment: @Slampy, у вас в примере не массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите. Если именно массивы нужны:

```
String[] b = Arrays.copyOf(titleList, titleList.length);
```

Насчет удаления тэгов можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "")
```